# What leads to system error in heremaps RoutingAPI call?

Tags: here-api

I am using heremaps calculate route api to get distance and time between two locations. I saw errors documentation and observed SYSTEM ERROR : errors that are thrown due to technical reasons. Can some one elaborate what might possibly lead to this type of error.

Comment: Please share your code and steps to reproduce the same error.

Comment: I am not getting error currently. But I have gone through errors in the here documentation and want to do validate accordingly before I face. So I wanted to know what circumstances will lead to this kind of error.

Comment: Do you have any idea what was the HTTP error code for this error.?

Answer (score 0):

Usually routing API cause error because the documentation request contains spaces in the request-

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4
&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
```

To avoid such type of error please remove all the spaces in the request like below-

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={}&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
```